# Multiple awk to print in the same line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have 5 files

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt 
d.txt 
e.txt
```

Pattern used

```
awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' a.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' b.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' c.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' d.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' e.txt;
```

Output

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

But I need it to be

```
a b c d e
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple awk. You can actually combine them in single awk:

```
awk FNR==21 {if (NR>FNR) printf OFS; printf $1}' {a,b,c,d,e}.txt
a b c d e
```

- `FNR==21` will run this block for line #21 in each input file
- `NR>FNR` will print a space for 2nd file onwards

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' a.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' b.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' c.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' d.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' e.txt; |tr '\n' ' '
```

Just add an `tr` command

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

pipe through xargs

```
awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' a.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' b.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' c.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' d.txt; awk 'NR==21 {print $1}' e.txt | xargs
```